# Has Hibernate 5 implemented DISCRIMINATOR approach for Multi-tenant data?

Tags: java, hibernate, orm, multi-tenant, hibernate-5.x

According to [hibernate 4 doc](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.1/devguide/en-US/html/ch16.html), the discriminator approach for multi-tenancy data was planned to be implemented on hibernate 5. However [hibernate 5 doc](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.0/userGuide/en-US/html_single/#d5e3243) is not up to date, it is still telling the same - 'Its support is planned for 5.0'.

So is it implemented or not? Any source telling more about it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The [HHH-6054](https://hibernate.atlassian.net/browse/HHH-6054) issue is still open, so Hibernate doesn't support this feature yet.

Answer (score 1):

Here are the docs referring to this. It is now available in Hibernate 6.

https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/6.0/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#multitenacy-hibernate-TenantId

Here is an example with Spring Boot

https://spring.io/blog/2022/07/31/how-to-integrate-hibernates-multitenant-feature-with-spring-data-jpa-in-a-spring-boot-application

Comment: A better link to docs (to @TenantId specifically): https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/6.0/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#multitenacy-hibernate-TenantId

Answer (score -1):

The [HHH-6054](https://hibernate.atlassian.net/browse/HHH-6054) issue is now resolved. The [docs](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.3/javadocs/org/hibernate/MultiTenancyStrategy.html) also don't mention that  `DISCRIMINATOR` cannot be used.

Comment: The issue is resolved as "Out of date" and not fixed. There are reasons to not remove an enum member even if it's not used.